# How to represent Dependency Triplets in .arff file format?

Tags: nlp, weka, feature-extraction, arff

I'm developing a classifier for text categorisation using Weka java libraries. I've extracted a number of features using Stanfords' CoreNLP package, including a dependency parse of the text which returns a string "(rel, head, mod)".

I was wanting to use the dependency triplets returned from this as features for classification but I cannot figure out how to properly represent them in the ARFF file. Basically, I'm stumped; for each instance, there are an arbitrary number of dependency triplets, so I can't define them explicitly in the attributes, for example:

```
@attribute entityCount numeric
@attribute depTriple_1 string
@attribute depTriple_2 string
.
.
@attribute depTriple_n string
```

Is there a particular way to go about this? I've spent the better part of the day searching and have not found anything yet.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from Weka Wiki:

```
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;

/**
 * Generates a little ARFF file with different attribute types.
 *
 * @author FracPete
 */
public class SO_Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FastVector      atts;
    FastVector      attsRel;
    FastVector      attVals;
    FastVector      attValsRel;
    Instances       data;
    Instances       dataRel;
    double[]        vals;
    double[]        valsRel;
    int             i;

    // 1. set up attributes
    atts = new FastVector();
    // - numeric
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("att1"));
    // - nominal
    attVals = new FastVector();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      attVals.addElement("val" + (i+1));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("att2", attVals));
    // - string
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("att3", (FastVector) null));
    // - date
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("att4", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
    // - relational
    attsRel = new FastVector();
    // -- numeric
    attsRel.addElement(new Attribute("att5.1"));
    // -- nominal
    attValsRel = new FastVector();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      attValsRel.addElement("val5." + (i+1));
    attsRel.addElement(new Attribute("att5.2", attValsRel));
    dataRel = new Instances("att5", attsRel, 0);
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("att5", dataRel, 0));

    // 2. create Instances object
    data = new Instances("MyRelation", atts, 0);

    // 3. fill with data
    // first instance
    vals = new double[data.numAttributes()];
    // - numeric
    vals[0] = Math.PI;
    // - nominal
    vals[1] = attVals.indexOf("val3");
    // - string
    vals[2] = data.attribute(2).addStringValue("This is a string!");
    // - date
    vals[3] = data.attribute(3).parseDate("2001-11-09");
    // - relational
    dataRel = new Instances(data.attribute(4).relation(), 0);
    // -- first instance
    valsRel = new double[2];
    valsRel[0] = Math.PI + 1;
    valsRel[1] = attValsRel.indexOf("val5.3");
    dataRel.add(new Instance(1.0, valsRel));
    // -- second instance
    valsRel = new double[2];
    valsRel[0] = Math.PI + 2;
    valsRel[1] = attValsRel.indexOf("val5.2");
    dataRel.add(new Instance(1.0, valsRel));
    vals[4] = data.attribute(4).addRelation(dataRel);
    // add
    data.add(new Instance(1.0, vals));

    // second instance
    vals = new double[data.numAttributes()];  // important: needs NEW array!
    // - numeric
    vals[0] = Math.E;
    // - nominal
    vals[1] = attVals.indexOf("val1");
    // - string
    vals[2] = data.attribute(2).addStringValue("And another one!");
    // - date
    vals[3] = data.attribute(3).parseDate("2000-12-01");
    // - relational
    dataRel = new Instances(data.attribute(4).relation(), 0);
    // -- first instance
    valsRel = new double[2];
    valsRel[0] = Math.E + 1;
    valsRel[1] = attValsRel.indexOf("val5.4");
    dataRel.add(new Instance(1.0, valsRel));
    // -- second instance
    valsRel = new double[2];
    valsRel[0] = Math.E + 2;
    valsRel[1] = attValsRel.indexOf("val5.1");
    dataRel.add(new Instance(1.0, valsRel));
    vals[4] = data.attribute(4).addRelation(dataRel);
    // add
    data.add(new Instance(1.0, vals));

    // 4. output data
    System.out.println(data);
  }
}
```

Your problem is in particular a "relational" attribute. This code segment has dealt with such relational attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I did it! Just posting this as an answer incase anyone else has a similar problem. Previously I was following the guide found on the Weka Wiki (as posted below by Rushdi), but I was having a lot of trouble following as the guide is creating static instances of the relational attribute, where as I required dynamic declarations of an arbitrary amount. So I decided to re-evaluate how I was generating the attributes, and I managed to get it to work with slight changes to the above guide:

```
    //1. Set up attributes
    FastVector atts;
    FastVector relAtts;
    Instances relData;
    atts = new FastVector();

    //Entity Count - numeric
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("entityCount"));

    //Dependencies - Relational (Multi-Instance)
    relAtts = new FastVector();


    relAtts.addElement(new Attribute("depTriplet", (FastVector) null));
    relData = new Instances("depTriples", relAtts, 0);


    atts.addElement(new Attribute("depTriples", relData, 0));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("postTxt", (FastVector) null));

    //2. Create Instances Object
    Instances trainSet = new Instances("MyName", atts, 0);

    /* 3. Fill with data:
       Loop through text docs to extract features 
          and generate instance for train set */
    //Holds the relational attribute instances
    Instances relAttData;

    for(Object doc: docList) {
        List<String> depTripleList = getDepTriples(doc);
        int entCount = getEntityCount(doc);
        String pt = getText(doc);

        //Create instance to be added to training set
        Instance tInst = new Instance(trainSet.numAttributes());

        //Entity count
        tInst.setValue( (Attribute) atts.elementAt(0), entCount);

        //Generate Instances for relational attribute
        relAttData = new Instances(trainSet.attribute(1).relation(), 0);

        //For each deplist entry, create an instance and add it to dataset
        for(String depTriple: depTripleList) {
             Instance relAttInst = new Instance(1);
             relAttInst.setDataset(relAttData);

             relAttInst.setValue(0, depTriple);

             relAttData.add(relAttInst);
        }

        //Add relational attribute (now filled with a number of Instances of attributes) to the main Instance
        tInst.setValue( (Attribute) atts.elementAt(1), trainSet.attribute(1).addRelation(relAttData));

       //Finally, add the instance to the relational attribute
       trainSet.add(tInst)
    }

    //4. Output data
    System.out.println(trainSet);
```

I realise this could probably be done differently, but this works well with my situation. Please keep in mind this is not my actual code, but an excerpt of multiple parts stitched together to demonstrate the process used to fix the problem.